How to convert a $2 \times 2$ matrix with entries of $4 \times 4$ matrices into a regular $8 \times 8 $ matrix
I have tried to create the following matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 0_{4} & \mathbb{I}_{4} \\ \mathbb{I}_{4} & 0_{4} \end{bmatrix}.$$
I have used the following code
matrix= {{Table[Table[0, {4}], {4}], IdentityMatrix[4]}, {IdentityMatrix[4], 
   Table[Table[0, {4}], {4}]}} // MatrixForm

which outputs the following: $$\begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \end{bmatrix}$$
Which is a $2 \times 2$ matrix with each entry in the form of a $4 \times 4$ matrix. I want to output just an $8 \times 8$ matrix.
However, my attempts with the \Flatten command have been fruitless.

Look up ArrayFlatten. And don't use MatrixForm for defining matrices – it is a display wrapper and interferes with evaluation!

z = ConstantArray[0, {4, 4}];
i = IdentityMatrix[4];

matrix = {{z, i}, {i, z}} // ArrayFlatten;
matrix // MatrixForm

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
